# Is it possible to perform passwordless authentication from a Linux server without using Kerberos authentication on SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server, linux, kubernetes

(A) Client PC (Windows)

(B) Web Server (virtual environment using Kubernetes)

(C) MS SQL Server (Windows)

Currently, Client PC (A) accesses MS SQL Server (C) with Windows authentication.
But The user needs to understand SQL to access the data, so I'm trying to create a UI by setting up a WebServer (B).
I need to use Kubernetes for the WebServer(B) due to restrictions, and I need to be able to access the database without a password.

MS SQL Server(C) is on the operations and I can't change it to Kerberos authentication.

Is there any way to achieve what I want to do? I would like to know if it is possible or not, and if not, please let me know that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I need to be able to use it with current Window authentication users.

Comment: Confused, Windows Authentication **is** Kerberos (or NTLM if the PC running SQL Server is not domain joined), it uses either a Kerberos ticket or NTLM hash to authenticate

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports NTLM and Kerberos for Windows Integrated Authentication, but also has its own SQL Server Authentication, where you simply present a user name and password to connect.  See [Authentication in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/authentication-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

It's very common for a web application to store a secret username and password to connect to SQL Server.